# Setting Variables Outside of Loop

Tags: apex

I'm having a silly hard time understanding how to do something in Apex (coming from Flows).

I'm looking to assign a field on the object that started the trigger to a variable, so I can use it in a loop.

Meaning:

Account launches trigger.

Grab a field on the account (let's say the account owner ID field for ease of question).

Assign that owner ID to a variable.

Then launch a loop that cycles through all the contacts related to the account, and assign that variable to a particular field.

All of that I can figure out, except initially assigning a variable outside of the loop, to use within the loop.

Anyone have any code lying around that does this and can be explained?

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the trigger in an after context.
2. Collect only the accounts that are relevant for the trigger. In this case, those who's owner has changed.
3. Since records coming into a trigger don't include their related objects, query for all the accounts that came into your trigger, including their contacts.
4. Loop through the accounts, update their contacts, collect the contacts into a list, update the list.

Example:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account(after update){
Set<Id> relevantAccountsIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Account acc : Trigger.new){
  if (acc.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId){
    relevantAccountsIds.add(acc.Id);
  }
 }
List<Contact> contactsForUpdate = new List<Contact>();
Map<Id, Account> triggerAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT OwnerId, (Select Account_Owner__c FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id in :Trigger.new]);
for (Account acc : triggerAccounts.Values()){
  for (Contact con : acc.Contacts){
    con.Account_Owner__c = acc.OwnerId;
    contactsForUpdate.add(con);
  }
 }
update contactsForUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This is what I ended up doing via looking at SF99 website, and it worked as intended!

Comment: Welcome to the site, @nick! If this is the solution can you mark it as the accepted answer?